# How to implement mutex in windows service

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, service, mutex

Hello I'm new in the threading topic, I need to add a Mutex in my windows service because whenever I run it, it pops over and over the awesome.exe that a fantastic.bat opens if it's closed.

***Fantastic.bat***

```
@echo off
:1
"C:\awesome.exe"
goto :1
```

I made a C# project to create a windows service, I followed up [this guide](http://www.nerdcorelabs.com/2014/06/how-to-create-windows-service-to-run.html), following up through it was pretty simple and voila! I got my windows service as expected, however I think a mutex would be an appropiate apporach in order to avoid getting lots of processes opening over and over again

***MyService.cs***

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Timers;

namespace Good_enough_service
{
    public partial class GoodService : ServiceBase
    {
        private Timer _syncTimer = null;
        public GoodService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            _syncTimer = new Timer();
            this._syncTimer.Interval = 1000;
            this._syncTimer.Elapsed +=
              new System.Timers.
                ElapsedEventHandler(this.syncTimerTicker);

            _syncTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {

            _syncTimer.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void syncTimerTicker(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\fantastic.bat");
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to install the service but it pops up a lot of times the bat and therefor it opens a lot of times my awesome.exe

I'm looking at a lot of examples of how to use a Mutex in stackoverflow, microsoft docs and google queries I find, however to be honest since I'm very new to this topic I'm kind of confused in how to build this up, can someone assist me in how to implement this?

***Program.cs*** This is part of the service project

```
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace Good_enough_service
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new GoodService()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're actually trying to do. It looks like your service just runs a batch on a timer, and that batch runs an .exe over and over again? A mutex is a tool for coordinating multiple threads, not multiple processes.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my answer back to you, I'm looking for a way to run my service that will run my ***Fantastic.bat*** so it opens up my ***awesome.exe*** whenever it's closed. Simple as that, however the issue I'm facing is that I'm a noob in this topics, I just followed up a guide on how to create a windows service and it's the code I published in my post, tbh I don't understand what parts to cut inside the code to avoid opening over and over the ***Fantastic.bat*** I know that if I increase the timer to 1 hour it will open up again the bat but process will duplicate X_X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your goal is just to start an `.exe` and make sure it keeps running, all you need to do is use a `Process` object to start the executable directly, and then monitor it for completion via the `HasExited` property. When the process exits, just start a new one (or restart the existing one).

[Process.HasExited Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_HasExited)

Comment: Looks like this is what I was looking for, thanks for the advice, I'll come back with the updated code